# How to calculate quantile of time in a queue of a queuing process?

Tags: queueing-systems

I want to calculate the 90th percentile of time spent in a queue. It seems that the way to do that is to generate `TemporalData` from `RandomFunction[QueueingProcess[6.4, 8], {0, 100}]` and call `Quantile` on that. The problem is that `RandomFunction` call above simulates the number of people in the queue and not the time spent in the queue.

How can I tell `RandomFunction` and `QueueingProcess` to "return" the time spent in the queue? Is there any other way to calculate the percentile of the time spent in an M/M/1 queue?

Comment: Would it be acceptable to calculate response time (queue time + service time)?

If the queue is first-come, first-serve the response time will have distribution `ExponentialDistribution[μ - λ]` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M/M/1_queue

Comment: Yes. It did not occur to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update 2

**For general G/G/c, FIFO ,$0<t<100$:**

We can first start by sampling the arrival times (we only have one queue). These will be distributed by a `RenewalProcess` with interarrival time distribution equal to the arrival rate distribution `arrRateDist`:

```
\[Lambda] = 6.4;
\[Mu] = 8;
c = 2;

arrRateDist = ExponentialDistribution[\[Lambda]];
servRateDist = ExponentialDistribution[\[Mu]];


SeedRandom[1234];
rf = RandomFunction[RenewalProcess[arrRateDist], {0, 100}];
arrivalTimes = rf["Path"][[All, 1]];
```

Now create a list `serverFinishTimes` with length equal to the number of servers `c`. This list contains the times at which the servers will finish their current job. If a server is free, their time in `serverFinishTimes` will be less than the current time. I initialize it as -1 so that they are considered free at t=0:

```
serverFinishTimes = ConstantArray[-1, c];
```

To calculate queue time, we will iterate over the `arrivalTimes`. We start by finding the next available server. We also calculate the gap between this time and the `arrivalTime` (`i` is iterating over `arrivalTime` here). `serverFinishTimes` is initially sorted, so the `serverFinishTimes[[1]]` is the time of the next available server:

```
nextServer = First@serverFinishTimes;
gap = nextServer - i;
```

If `gap<0`, then a server is immediately available and there is no queue time. If `gap>0` then the queue time is exactly `gap`:

```
q = gap * UnitStep[gap];
```

Now we need to update the `serverFinishTimes` to reflect their new jobs. First we sample the service time:

```
thisServeTime = RandomVariate@servRateDist;
```

If the server was free before their next job arrived, then we first need to move their time over to the next job arrival time, as they didn't start the job until then. We then add the service time:

```
If[q == 0, serverFinishTimes[[1]] = i];
serverFinishTimes[[1]] += thisServeTime;
```

We finally sort the `serverFinishTimes` so that the first element `serverFinishTimes[[1]]`  will be the next soonest available server.

```
serverFinishTimes = Sort[serverFinishTimes];
```

putting this all together:

```
\[Lambda] = 6.4;
\[Mu] = 8;
c = 1;

arrRateDist = ExponentialDistribution[\[Lambda]];
servRateDist = ExponentialDistribution[\[Mu]];



SeedRandom[1234];
rf = RandomFunction[RenewalProcess[arrRateDist], {0, 100}];
arrivalTimes = rf["Path"][[All, 1]];


serverFinishTimes = ConstantArray[-1, c];
qTimes =
  Table[
   nextServer = First@serverFinishTimes;
   gap = nextServer - i;
   q = gap UnitStep[gap];
   
  thisServeTime = RandomVariate@servRateDist;
   If[q == 0, serverFinishTimes[[1]] = i];
   serverFinishTimes[[1]] += thisServeTime;
   
   
   
   serverFinishTimes = Sort[serverFinishTimes];
   q
   , {i, arrivalTimes}];
Quantile[qTimes, 0.9]

(*1.70407*)

Histogram[qTimes, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"wait time", "counts"}, LabelStyle -> Medium]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As expected, changing `c=2` greatly reduces nonzero waiting probability as $\frac{6.4}{8*2} = 0.4$ is far below 1:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

### **Update**

**For M/M/1 only, FIFO, $0<t<100$**

I will post when I have a method for M/M/c.

Notice that the `RandomFunction` data is just timestamps of every time a person either enters or finishes waiting in the queue:

```
\[Lambda] = 64/10;
\[Mu] = 8;


SeedRandom[1234];
MMCProc = \[ScriptCapitalQ] = QueueingProcess[\[Lambda], \[Mu]];
rf = RandomFunction[MMCProc, {0, 100}]

path = rf["Path"];
Differences@path[[All, 2]]
(*{1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1,...}*)
```

If we assume FIFO (first-in, first-out) queue discipline, then we can exactly calculate the queue times from the data  the following method:

1. Record the timestamp of an event
2. If it's someone joining the queue (`Differences@path[[All, 2]]` will be +1 at that index), add the timestamp to the bottom of a list containing the arrival times of people currently in queue.
3. If it's someone leaving the queue (`Differences@path[[All, 2]]` will be -1 at that index), record the time difference between the first element in the arrival times list (the person who's been in line the longest), and drop that first element from the arrival times list (note that this method would be invalid if our queue was not FIFO).

So let's first create our data, which will consist of the even timestamp, and a 1 or -1 depending on whether someone left or entered queue:

```
path = rf["Path"];
inOrOut = Differences@path[[All, 2]];
times=Rest@path[[All,1]];
data = Thread[{times, inOrOut}];
```

And since we assume FIFO, we can find the times in system (queue+service times) by finding the arrival and departure times and subtracting them:

```
arrivalTimes = Select[data, Last[#] == 1 &][[All, 1]];
leaveTimes = Select[data, Last[#] == -1 &][[All, 1]];
arrivalTimes = Take[arrivalTimes, Length@leaveTimes];
qTimes = leaveTimes - arrivalTimes;
```

Notice I take `Take[arrivalTimes, Length@leaveTimes];`. This is because there may still be people in the queue at the end when t=100.

And now we can histogram and calculate 90% quantile:

```
Histogram[qTimes, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"wait time", "counts"}, LabelStyle -> Medium]
Quantile[qTimes, 0.9]
(*plot below*)
(*1.7706*)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

### Original Answer

I don't know how to get queueing time data from a `QueueingProcess`, but this a workaround to estimate the distribution of the response time (queuing + service time) using the data we have. I also assume the queue is first-come, first-serve.

A process of the form `QueueingProcess[λ, μ]` is an [M/M/1 queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M/M/1_queue).
Assuming first-come, first-serve, the response time of M/M/1 queue will be distributed as `ExponentialDistribution[μ-λ]` (for μ>λ), where `μ = 8` is the service rate, and `λ = 6.4` is the arrival rate.

Therefore in this case, the queue time + service time will follow `responseTime = ExponentialDistribution[1.6];` and 90th percentile `Quantile[responseTime, 0.9]` of `1.43912`.

If we don't know the parameters `λ`, `μ`, we can instead get the parameters from the `EstimatedProcess` of our `RandomFunction` data.
First simulate the process:

```
λ = 6.4;
μ = 8;
queue = QueueingProcess[λ, μ];

SeedRandom[1234];
rf = RandomFunction[q, {0, 100}];
```

Then find the estimated M/M/1 `QueueingProcess` and grab the estimated parameters:

```
est = EstimatedProcess[rf, QueueingProcess[lam, mu]];
{λFit, μFit} = {QueueProperties[est, "ArrivalRate"], 
   QueueProperties[est, "ServiceRate"]}
(*{6.87068, 7.78525}*)
```

And use the estimated parameters to estimate the response time distribution and 90% quantile:

```
responseTime = ExponentialDistribution[μFit - λFit];

Quantile[responseTime, 0.9]
(*2.51766*)
```

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful!

Comment: However, I am still wondering how to get the right data from a simulation process. Queue time for the M/M/1 queue follows a known distribution. What about 
M/M/2 queue or a queue network for which there is no known queue time distribution?

Comment: Added method for directly calculating queue time (not response time) directly from data. If you use `RandomFunction` without a time step specification (like we do here), then it will just return the timestamp for every time someone enters or leaves (finishes waiting) in queue. So assuming FIFO we can calculate queue times.

Comment: Also note this will work for any general G/G/c queue process, so long as it is FIFO

Comment: Nevermind, I just realized I made a big mistake. The value of QueuingProcess is the number of people in the system, not the queue. So this method only works for M/M/1 data unless there’s a way to record which server each customer gets served by. I’m not home now so I’ll have to fix this later

Comment: Fixed. Maybe there is a way to do this without making my own sampling model for the system, but that's what I did here.